# Given a triangleIndex how do you find the global position of a mesh vertex - Unity

Tags: unity, procedural-generation, mesh

For Unity's mesh system - Given a triangleIndex how do you find the global position of a mesh vertex (of a meshfilter on a gameobject)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // Read the mesh without copying it.
    var mesh = meshFilter.sharedMesh;

    // Cache these if you're going to be querying the same mesh a lot,
    // or use their List overrides to re-use the same managed memory.
    var allIndices = mesh.GetIndices(0);  // 0 = Sub-mesh 0
    var allVertices = mesh.vertices;

    // It takes 3 indices to make a triangle,
    // so the 0th triangle starts at index 0, the next starts at index 3...
    int firstIndexLocation = hit.triangleIndex * 3;
    // (Here I assume you're reading the triangle index out of a raycast hit)

    // Read three consecutive vertex indices, 
    // and use them to look up the corresponding vertex, in local space.
    var myVerts = new Vector3[] {
        allVertices[allIndices[firstIndexLocation + 0]],
        allVertices[allIndices[firstIndexLocation + 1]],
        allVertices[allIndices[firstIndexLocation + 2]]
    };

    // Convert your vertices from local space to world space.
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        myVerts[i] = meshFilter.transform.TransformPoint(myVerts[i]);
    }

    // myVerts now contains the three vertices of the hit triangle, in world space.
```

Comment: hmm okay so i get a triangle index from RaycastHit hit.triangleIndex - i assume that's the triangle index corresponding to a specific vertex?

Comment: A triangle corresponds to three vertices.

Comment: is there a way to find out which vertex was hit from raycasthit?

Comment: Raycasts typically do not hit vertices, they hit triangles. A vertex has zero area, so hitting one exactly with a raycast is very difficult. But you could hit a triangle *very close* to a particular vertex. Are you interested in finding the vertex closest to the point where the raycast hit the triangle?

Comment: yes, how do you find the closest vertex